# Issues with a query

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble getting this query to work.

What its suppose to do is find the information on the last post made in a forum and it subforums. It works if the last post was made in that forum, but if it was made in a sub-forum it doesn't work correctly.

I have a feeling the problem is around the WHERE, but I'm not quite sure...

Any ideas?

```
// Last Post Info
$lastpost_sql = "
    SELECT
        forum_posts.post_id AS post_id,
        forum_posts.post_date AS post_date,
        forum_posts.thread_id AS thread_id,
        temp.thread_title AS thread_title,
        temp.forum_id AS forum_id,
        users.user_id AS user_id,
        users.user_firstname AS user_firstname,
        users.user_lastname AS user_lastname
    FROM (
        SELECT
            forum_threads.thread_id,
            forum_threads.thread_title,
            forum_threads.forum_id
        FROM
            forums AS t1
            LEFT JOIN
                forums AS t2 ON t2.forum_parent = t1.forum_id
            LEFT JOIN
                forums AS t3 ON t3.forum_parent = t2.forum_id
            INNER JOIN
                forum_threads ON forum_threads.forum_id = t1.forum_id OR forum_threads.forum_id = t2.forum_id OR forum_threads.forum_id = t3.forum_id
        WHERE
            t1.forum_id = '$forum2[id]'
        GROUP BY
            forum_threads.thread_id
    )
    AS
        temp
    INNER JOIN
        forum_posts ON forum_posts.thread_id = temp.thread_id
    INNER JOIN
        users ON forum_posts.user_id = users.user_id
    ORDER BY
        forum_posts.post_id DESC LIMIT 1
";
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the table structure and a description of the result set you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry. Thought you could figure it out based on the query. Hold on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your subquery.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    thread_id,
    thread_title,
    forum_id
FROM
    forum_threads 
WHERE
    forum_id = '$forum2[id]'
    OR forum_id = (SELECT forum_parent 
                    FROM forums 
                    WHERE forum_id = '$forum2[id]')
    OR forum_id = (SELECT forum_parent 
                    FROM forums 
                    WHERE forum_id = (SELECT forum_parent 
                                        FROM forums 
                                        WHERE forum_id = '$forum2[id]'))
```

That should go two levels deep into the sub-forums and grab every thread.